# In angular2 my component can't bind to the model and display in the html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**This is my module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [FooterComponent],
  exports: [FooterComponent],
  providers: []
})

export class FooterModule { }
```

**This is my component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'FooterComponent',
  templateUrl: 'footer.component.html'
})

export class FooterComponent {
  email: string = "";

  constructor() {
    console.log("footer!");

    this.email = "test";
  }

}
```

**This is my html:**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                 

     <input class="form-control" type="email" value="" placeholder="Email address" [(ngModel)]="email">

</div>
```

All I want to do is see the model email 2 way bind to the view.

**Error I get in the console is:**

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("

*Let me know if you require anymore files

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag as well?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yeh I have a form tag. I'm just trying to get it working - very basic binding

Answer (score 0):

`BrowserModule` should only be added to `imports` in the root module `AppModule` but not on other modules. (`CommonModule` only needs to be added to non-root modules, but that doesn't hurt on the root module)